# Loading the same image in different urls

Tags: optimization, pageload, image-loading, page-load-time

I have an image loaded in a web page say http://example.com/test.jpg on example.com

Now, say if, via a hyperlink on that page, the user goes to example.com/testpage.html where the same image is present (with src http://example.com/test.jpg), then would the browser request that image from the server again?

P.S.: The problem I am facing is slow page rendering on a single html page due to lots of images & javascript. So I plan to load some images on the previous referrer url so that when the user enters the page, some images have already been loaded. Note that I do not plan to load the page asynchronously via js/ajax. I want to do a simple redirect to the given page & want some images to be already loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the domain is the same, and your caching is set up normally, the browser will make a request, but get a *304 Not modified* response, and not need to re-download the entire asset again.

Comment: An easy way to verify this is to use the firebug extension (or a similar tool) to watch the files that are requested, as well as the responses. This may also help you pinpoint any particularly slow assets.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer, though any external references would prove more useful. thanks btw.

Comment: Thank you. If you want to know more about the various responses, including 304, you can check out the RFC here - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html . As far as firebug, you can find that here - https://getfirebug.com/ , although chrome and ie have a similar tool built in. Sometimes the best way to know exactly what is happening is to fire up the page in the browser, and watch what happens (this is the "net" tab, in firebug, btw). Your caching idea will accomplish what you want, but ddyer does also make a good point about looking for possible opportunities for optimization.

Comment: You might also check out http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/ ...

Comment: One last thing - all of these requests are less expensive than a "full" request, but they still use resources. If it has to make a million requests, it's still a lot of "work", even with the caching. You mentioned javascript, and a common way to accomplish a similar thing with javascript, as you hope to with images, is to combine all of your javascript files into one file, to take advantage of caching, and make fewer requests. Depending on your environment, it may even do this for you automatically (like Rails).

Comment: thanks, but one last question. Are js files also cached. Say if I use jquery in one page, & also in the next page would it use the same cached file?

Comment: Yep, exactly. javascript, images, CSS, you name it - pretty much all assets, really.

Comment: Can you please add some references to this answer? where can this be checked?

Comment: @trainoasis it's easy to verify yourself - just check the first few comments to this answer. (since this answer was created, all major browsers have built in developer tools, so it is even easier than before)

Answer (score 1):

The browser may or may not make a request for the image again - it depends on the browser, how old the image is, when it was last retrieved etc.

When the browser comes across the request it will first check it's cache for the URL

If the item is in the cache and there is an explicit expiry date set on for it (via either expires or cache-control: max-age), and that expiry is in the future then the browser will use the version in cache.

If the item is in cache and there is no future expiry date then the browser can use heuristics to judge whether to it needs to make a request e.g. if it downloaded it yesterday and the file hasn't changed for 6 months it may decide to use the version in cache (it's not clear which browsers do what on this at the moment)

Alternatively if the item is in cache, the browser can do an "if-modified-since" request and if the resource hasn't changed since the date of the cached version the server responds with 304, otherwise it sends the file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple image reference ought to be cached and only loaded once.

You should check the size of the images - maybe you've got a huge image (that is slow to load) that is being displayed much smaller and could be resized on the server.